# Vanilla ASP.NET and REST

Tags: asp.net, rest

I wish to implement REST service which will be integrated with ASP site (basically the same project).

I've tried to provide my custom `VirtualPathProvider` (`VPP`) and it works, but to a certain degree. First, the `content-type` of the response is always `application/octet-stream`. Second, only `GET` requests are piped through the `VPP`. I've seen people playing around with `HttpApplication` to solve these problems. I am not sure if I wish to follow the path of hacking the ASP as it might take a lot of time, and in the end it might be simply impossible to accomplish the task.

Is there a way to do it, or I should create a separate page for MVC, and talk with it via some inter-process communication. This way MVC will be handle the REST requests and call my code in response. And *vice versa* - ASP will be able to send REST requests to remote servers.

If there are any other, cleaner, safer & easier, ways of linking MVC with vanilla ASP, then feel free to post them in comments/answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VirtualPathProvider` is meant to be a way to virtualize the filesystem for internal ASP.NET operations (e.g. storing *.aspx and *.master files in a database), it is only coincidental that it works for user-provided URIs and requests.

Your best bet is just to use ASP.NET MVC, which is now integrated with ASP.NET (since 4.x) or as an easily redistributable component in .NET 3.x. ASP.NET MVC does play nice with WinForms in the same application, so don't reinvent the wheel.

However, if you are insistent, the only real option is to do it all from within a custom `IHttpHandler` that chooses to handle incoming requests or not (as you won't have ASP.NET URL Routing because you're not using ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: Hi Dai, sounds like you're the right one to answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061602/how-to-fake-a-directory-listing-in-iis-virtualpathprovider-works-for-file-but, thanks

Comment: @Dai Is it possible to have MVC and ASP projects run together, or one of them has to be the default one (MVC in this case) which hosts the other?